# (推量形+) というものだ: nuance and function?

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

> 1. 圧倒的だなんて言葉では表現しきれない、絶望的な戦力差である。
>
> しかもそれらが皆、親でも殺されたかのような調子で士道に憎々しげな視線を送ってきているのだ。どれだけ肝が据わった人間でも汗くらい滲ませよう**というものである**。
>
> 2. だが、改変後の折紙の意識が『士道への思い三〇パーセント:節度七〇パーセント』だったところに、『士道への思い一二〇パーセント』が足されたなら、バランスも崩壊してしまおう**というものだった**。

Hi. Are both というものだs used to emphasize the speakers’ assumptions (推量形:〜よう)? If not, what nuance would they have?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can understand ～(よ)う and ものだ separately.

Comment: @naruto Thank you. I have learned the functions of ものだ before. But recently I have found an explanation here, which is a bit different from my original thinking. Do you agree with the explanation in the link?https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1115694046